# Coolant leaked out of vehicle

Tags: cooling

I have no coolant in my vehicle.  It's getting cold tonight-20 degrees.  Can I leave the vehicle parked, then just add coolant when the weather warms up again?  The coolant all leaked out, I don't need to use the vehicle for a few days.  Thanks!

Comment: How have you confirmed all the coolant is out?

Answer (score 2):

If ALL the coolant has come out then that will be fine.

BUT, if the coolant is not anti-freeze protected and there is some left in the engine or heater core or pipes then that can still freeze and cause damage.

Be very sure it is empty if the coolant is not treated with an anti-freeze product.